# UWSGI not running flask app when debugging due to postfork

Tags: python, nginx, flask, pydev, uwsgi

I have setup a basic Flask app that is using `pydevd` to remote debug our python app. We are also using the uwsgidecorators's `postfork()` method. The code looks something like this

```
from flask import Flask

import sys
sys.path.append('pycharm-debug.egg')  # replace by pycharm-debug.egg for Python 2.7
import pydevd
# the following line can be copied from "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=4444, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)


print __name__

application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


def initialize():
    print "This is called"


try:
    from uwsgidecorators import postfork
    postfork(initialize)
except ImportError:
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8055)
```

The uWSGI.ini file looks like this

```
[uwsgi]
module = app
socket = 0.0.0.0:8000
master = true
```

Now when I try to run the `uwsgi ./uwsgi.ini` the debugger does break on the first line i.e. on `print __name__` but the application doesn't start up. One thing to note is that postfork() doesn't call the `intialize` method. After some trial and error I was able to run the application if I removed the `pydev.settrace` I need to be able to debug the application. Does anyone know what is going on here?